# Cronômetro Regressivo Completo em JS Puro - Contagem Problemática

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

**Gente, estou criando um cronômetro regressivo acompanhado dos botões (iniciar, pausar, resetar, reiniciar e salvar tempo) sendo que o tempo inicial é definido num input também.**

Procurei diversas vezes em diversas postagens no pt.stackoverflow e em outros fóruns da internet, achei no máximo cronômetros regressivos, mas não com as mesmas funcionalidades e apesar de ter tentado adaptar não consegui. Em nosso fórum só se encontra perguntas parecidas, mas a linguagem não é a mesma e quando é (js puro), a finalidade é muito diferente.

**Meu código está com problema de contagem, já observei problemas quando são mais que 10 minutos ou menos que 1. Gostaria de uma resolução em JS Puro! Observe o código:**

Javascript

```
    function transporta(mensagem){
            var docsetmin = document.getElementById('setminutos');
            var docsetsec = document.getElementById('setsegundos');
            var docrestamin = document.getElementById('restamin');
            var docrestasec = document.getElementById('restasec');

            if(docsetsec.value <= 59){
                docrestamin.value = docsetmin.value;
                docrestasec.value = docsetsec.value;
                setTimeout(cronometro, 1000, 'start');
            }
            else{
                alert('Há problemas com o tempo configurado!');
            }

        }

        function cronometro(option, message){

            var docsetmin = document.getElementById('setminutos');
            var docsetsec = document.getElementById('setsegundos');
            var docrestamin = document.getElementById('restamin');
            var docrestasec = document.getElementById('restasec');
            var docsetminval = docsetmin.value;
            var docsetsecval = docsetsec.value;
            var docrestaminval = docrestamin.value;
            var docrestasecval = docrestasec.value;

            if(option == 'start'){
                start(message);
            }
            if(option == 'pause'){
                docrestamin.placeholder = docrestamin.value;
                docrestasec.placeholder = docrestasec.value;
                alert('Cronômetro Pausado');
                docrestamin.value = '--';
                docrestasec.value = '--';
                document.getElementById('paused').innerHTML = 'Pausado em: ' + docrestamin.placeholder + ':' + docrestasec.placeholder + '.';
            }
            if(option == 'reset'){
                docsetmin.value = '00';
                docsetsec.value = '00';
                docrestamin.value = '00';
                docrestasec.value = '00';
                docrestamin.placeholder = '';
                docrestasec.placeholder = '';
                docsetmin.placeholder = '';
                docsetsec.placeholder = '';
            }
            if(option == 'resume'){
                document.getElementById('paused').innerHTML = '';
                docrestamin.value = docrestamin.placeholder;
                docrestasec.value = docrestasec.placeholder;
                cronometro('start', message);
            }
            if(option == 'save'){
                alert(docsetmin.value + ':' + docsetsec.value);
            }
        }

        function start(alerta){


            var docsetmin = document.getElementById('setminutos');
            var docsetsec = document.getElementById('setsegundos');
            var docrestamin = document.getElementById('restamin');
            var docrestasec = document.getElementById('restasec');

            /* Se for mais que 10 minutos */
            if(docrestamin.value > 10){

                /* Se for mais que 10 segundos */
                if((docrestasec.value <= 59) && (docrestasec.value > 10)){
                    docrestasec.value = docrestasec.value - 1;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000);        
                }

                /* Se for menor ou igual a 10 segundos e mais que 0 segundos */
                if((docrestasec.value <= 10) && (docrestasec.value > 0)){
                    var ts = docrestasec.value - 1;
                    docrestasec.value = '0' + ts;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');
                }

                /* Se for menor ou igual a 0 segundos */
                if(docrestasec.value <= 0){
                    docrestasec.value = '59';
                    docrestamin.value = docrestamin.value - 1;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');   
                }
            }

            /* Se for menor ou igual a 10 minutos e mais que 0 minutos */
            if((docrestamin.value <= 10) && (docrestamin.value > 0)){

                /* Se for mais que 10 segundos */
                if((docrestasec.value > 10) && (docrestasec.value <= 59)){
                    docrestasec.value = docrestasec.value - 1;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');    
                }

                /* Se for menor ou igual a 10 segundos e mais que 0 segundos */
                if(docrestasec.value <= 10 && docrestasec.value > 0){
                    var ts = docrestasec.value - 1;
                    docrestasec.value = '0' + ts;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');
                }

                /* Se for menor ou igual a 0 segundos */
                if(docrestasec.value <= 0){
                    var tm = docrestamin.value - 1;
                    docrestamin.value = '0' + tm;
                    docrestasec.value = 59;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');
                }
            }

            /* Se for menor ou igual a 0 minutos */
            if(docrestamin.value <= 0){

                /* Se for mais que 10 segundos */
                if((docrestasec.value <= 59) && (docrestasec.value > 10)){
                    docrestasec.value = docrestasec.value - 1;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');
                }

                /* Se for menor ou igual a 10 segundos e mais que 0 segundos */
                if((docrestasec.value <= 10) && (docrestasec.value > 0)){
                    var ts = docrestasec.value - 1;
                    docrestasec.value = '0' + ts;
                    setTimeout(start, 1000, 'start');    
                }

                /* Se for menor ou igual a 0 segundos */
                if(docrestasec.value <= 0){
                    if((docrestamin.value = '00') && (docrestasec.value = '00')){
                        alert('O tempo acabou!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function Onlynumbers(){
            var tecla = event.keyCode;
            if((tecla >= "48") && (tecla <= "57") && (tecla = "186")){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

CSS3

```
    body{padding: 20%;}
        header{text-align: center;}
        section{align-items: center; justify-content: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;}
        .btn{color: black; border: none; background-color: white; margin-left: 0.5%; margin-right: 0.5%; text-align: center;}
        .border{border: 1px solid black;}
        .border{transition: background-color 0.4s ease-in 0.2s; transition: color 0.01s ease-in;}
        .border:hover{background-color: #1397D4; color: white;}
```

HTML

```
    <!-- Cronômetro Regressivo -->
    <header>
        <p><h1>Cronômetro Regressivo</h1></p>
    </header>
    <br>
    <section>
        <input placeholder="m" class="btn" id="setminutos" type="text" name="minutos" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers()">
        :
        <input placeholder="s" class="btn" id="setsegundos" maxlength="2" type="text" name="segundos" size="2" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers()">
            <button id="comece" class="btn border" type="button" onclick="transporta()">Iniciar</button>               
            <button class="btn border" onclick="cronometro('pause');">Pausar</button>
            <button class="btn border" onclick="cronometro('reset')">Resetar</button>
            <button class="btn border" onclick="cronometro('resume')">Reiniciar</button>
            <button class="btn border" onclick="cronometro('save')">Salvar Tempo</button>



                <input class="btn dnone" id="restamin" type="text" name="minutosresta" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers()">
                <div class="dnone">:</div>
                <input class="btn dnone" id="restasec" maxlength="2" type="text" name="segundosresta" size="2" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers()">
                <div id="paused" class="dnone"></div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

segue codigo html, css e javascript. copie o codigo em tres arquivos separados e faça a modificação a seu gosto:

```js
var configMinuto;
var configSegundo;
var mostrarValor;
var evento = null;
var contador = null;
var minuto = 0;
var segundo = 0;

function IniciarCronometro(valor){
 this.evento = valor;
 this.configMinuto = document.getElementById('min').value;
 this.configSegundo = document.getElementById('seg').value;
 this.mostrarValor = document.getElementById('mostrarValor');
 
 
 if (evento=="start"){
  if(!document.getElementById('min').readOnly){
   if(!this.validarNumero(this.configMinuto)){
    alert("Campo minuto não é um número!");
    return;
   }
   if(!this.validarNumero(this.configSegundo) || document.getElementById('seg').value > 59){
    alert("Campo segundo não é um número válido (0 a 59)!");
    return;
   }
   
   document.getElementById('min').readOnly = true;
   document.getElementById('seg').readOnly = true;
   document.getElementById('btnIniciar').disabled  = true;
   document.getElementById('btnResetar').disabled  = false;
   document.getElementById('btnPausar').disabled  = false;
   this.minuto = document.getElementById('min').value;
   this.segundo = document.getElementById('seg').value;
   
   document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.remove('mostrarValor');
   document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.add('mostrarValor2');
   document.getElementById('exibe').classList.remove('Classexibe');
   document.getElementById('exibe').classList.add('Classexibe2');
   
  }else{
   if(this.segundo == 0 && this.minuto != 0){
    this.segundo = 59;
    this.minuto--;
   }else{
    this.segundo--;
   }
   if(this.minuto == 0 && this.segundo == 0){
    document.getElementById('min').readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById('seg').readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById('btnIniciar').disabled  = false;
    document.getElementById('btnResetar').disabled  = true;
    document.getElementById('btnPausar').disabled  = true;
    this.mostrarValor.value = "00:00";
    
    document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.remove('mostrarValor2');
    document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.add('mostrarValor');
    document.getElementById('exibe').classList.remove('Classexibe2');
    document.getElementById('exibe').classList.add('Classexibe');
   
    clearTimeout(this.contador);
    return;
   } 
   
   novoMinuto = null;
   novoSegundo = null;
   if(this.minuto <= 9){
    novoMinuto = "0" + this.minuto;
   }else{
    novoMinuto = this.minuto;
   }
   if(this.segundo <= 9){
    novoSegundo = "0" + this.segundo;
   }else{
    novoSegundo = this.segundo;
   }
   this.mostrarValor.value = novoMinuto + ":" + novoSegundo;
  }
 }
 clearTimeout(this.contador);
 this.contador = setTimeout('IniciarCronometro(evento)', 1000);
}

function validarNumero(valor){
 return !isNaN(parseFloat(valor)) && isFinite(valor);
}



function PausarCronometro(){
 if(document.getElementById('btnPausar').value=="PAUSAR"){
  document.getElementById('btnPausar').value = "VOLTAR";
  this.evento = "pause";
 }else{
  document.getElementById('btnPausar').value = "PAUSAR";
  this.evento = "start";
 }
}

function ResetarCronometro(){
 document.getElementById('min').readOnly = false;
 document.getElementById('seg').readOnly = false;
 document.getElementById('btnIniciar').disabled  = false;
 document.getElementById('btnResetar').disabled  = true;
 document.getElementById('btnPausar').disabled  = true;
 document.getElementById('btnPausar').value = "PAUSAR";
 this.mostrarValor.value = "00:00";

document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.remove('mostrarValor2');
 document.getElementById('mostrarValor').classList.add('mostrarValor');
 document.getElementById('exibe').classList.remove('Classexibe2');
 document.getElementById('exibe').classList.add('Classexibe');

 clearTimeout(this.contador);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 99%;
}
body {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.mostrarValor{
 text-align: center;
 border:0px solid white;
 font-size: 50pt;
}
.mostrarValor2{
 text-align: center;
 border:0px solid white;
 font-size: 50pt;
 animation: fade 10000ms infinite;
}

.Classexibe{
 text-align:center;
}
.Classexibe2{
 text-align:center;
 animation: fade 10000ms infinite;
}
section {
 width: 450px;
}

.btn {
 
 width:100px;
}


@keyframes fade {
 0% {bakcground-color:white;}
 25% {background-color:orange;}
 50% {background-color:green;}
 75% {background-color:red;}
 100% {background-color:white;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>CRONÔMETRO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <section>
  <article>
   <fieldset class="Classexibe" id="exibe"><legend>Exibição</legend>
    <p><input class="mostrarValor" type="text" id="mostrarValor" size="2" readonly="readonly" value="00:00"/></p>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset><legend>Configuração</legend>
    <p><label for="min">Colocar minutos: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="text" id="min" size="2" maxlength="3"/></p>
    <p><label for="seg">Colocar segundos: </label><input type="text" id="seg" size="2" maxlength="2"/></p>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset><legend>Comandos</legend>
    <p>
     <input class="btn" type="button" value="INICIAR" id="btnIniciar" onclick="IniciarCronometro('start')" /> 
     <input class="btn" type="button" value="PAUSAR" id="btnPausar" onclick="PausarCronometro()" disabled="disabled" /> 
     <input class="btn" type="button" value="RESETAR" id="btnResetar" onclick="ResetarCronometro()" disabled="disabled" /> 
    </p>
   </fieldset>
  </article>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Saulo! Muito obrigado por me ajudar... Estava desesperado, recomecei do 0 com o switch e deu certo! Gostei muito da sua lógica! Se possível, pode me explicar o clearTimeout e o ParseFloat? Obs.: O input #mostrarValor tem que ter o size 5, para o tempo poder ser visualizado por completo... Muito obg! Salvou muito!

Comment: clearTimeout cancela o setTimeout. Coloquei o setTimeout em uma variável global para poder cancelar com a função clearTimeout.
Já o ParseFloat() pega os primeiros caracteres separado por espaço e converte em um float (número real).
O ideal é contar em milisegundos e essa contagem em milisegundos mudar mudar o segundo e o segundo mudar o minuto. No exemplo que fiz, coloquei o segundo para mudar o minuto. digo isso porque se pausar, haverá uma pequena defasagem ao retornar mas como disse, é resolvido colocando em milisegundos.
Abraço